# Numerate, store and plot the intersection points of lines and a polygon

Tags: matlab

How can I numerate, store in an array and plot/point the intersection coordinates of the lines and the polygon? Any idea how to indicate that a line has many intersection points?

Code:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
% draw angle lines
xCenter = 17;
yCenter = 8;
poly1 = polyshape([ 15 15 20 15 10],[ 10 0 10 15 0]);
plot(poly1)
hold on;
L=15; %Line length, can be changed
angle = 25; %Choose angle, can be more
  
for langle =  0:angle:360 
    langle
    x2=xCenter+ L * cosd(langle);
    y2=yCenter+ L * sind(langle);    
    line([xCenter,x2], [yCenter,y2], 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 1);
    lineseg = [xCenter,x2; yCenter,y2];
    [in,out] = intersect(poly1,lineseg);    
end
```

Comment: Use the function [polyxpoly](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/polyxpoly.html) to get the intersection of the line with the polygon, and then use the [text](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) function to add numbering of each intersection on the plot.

Comment: Thanks but I do not have Mapping Toolbox.